# Trying to implement timer and perform tasks every x seconds but the tasks seem to get delayed

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I'm writing an app where a user specifies a length of time, length of an interval and a length of time in between intervals. I want to have a timer label showing the user the total time but then I also want to have a label showing the work status (recording if in the interval, break if between interval time and break end).

Heres an Example: Total time = 2 min, Interval = 20 seconds, Break = 10 seconds

In this example there will be 4 intervals. So from 0:00-0:19 I want to display "Recording" and then from 0:20-0:29 I want to display break and then from 0:30-0:49 I display "Recording" and 0:50-0:59 I display "Break" and so on. All while the timer counts the time.

So I thought this would be pretty straightforward but what seems to happen is the timer increments properly but after the 1st interval the label doesnt switch from break to recording until 0:31 or 0:32 so it looks a little delayed.

Here is the code I am using currently (Note obs is an object Im passing in that has data from user input).

```
int TotalInterval = obs.Interval + obs.Break;
int WorkingInterval = obs.Interval;
int NumberOfIntervals = (obs.Duration*60) / TotalInterval;
DateTime ObservationEnd = obs.DateCreated.AddMinutes(obs.Duration);

Timer.Text = "Starting Timer";
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;
int InIntervalCounter = 0;
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
{
    // called every 1 second
    Timer.Text = "Started";

    if (ObservationEnd < DateTime.UtcNow)
    {
      Timer.Text = "Time Over";
      Results.IsVisible = true;                    
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
      seconds++;
      InIntervalCounter++;

      if (InIntervalCounter > WorkingInterval)
        IntervalOrBreak.Text = "Break";

      if (InIntervalCounter > TotalInterval)
      {
        IntervalOrBreak.Text = "Recording";
        InIntervalCounter = 0;
      }
      Timer.Text = "Time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds.ToString("D2");

      return true; 
    }                
});
```

I'm pretty new to app development/xamarin so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: first, try using System.Timers.Timer instead - it's much better.  Second, use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() when you need to update your UI from a background thread

Comment: I would suggest that you don't try and count seconds; Timer's don't fire very accurately.  Take a timestamp at the start of your process and configure a timer that fires every 0.1 second or so. Then compute the elapsed time based on the start timestamp and the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try using simple Threads with Thead.sleep() like this:

```
 final long delay_millis = 100;
 Thread thread_something;

 thread_something = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                     long start_time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                     // Do some task

                     long time_need_for_delay = (start_time + delay_millis) - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                    if(time_need_for_delay > 0)
                           thread_something.sleep(time_need_for_delay);

                } catch (Exception e) { }
            }
        }
    });

thread_something.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

> after the 1st interval the label doesnt switch from break to recording
>   until 0:31 or 0:32 so it looks a little delayed.

If you want to display break from 0:20-0:29 and display "Recording" from 0:30-0:49, I think the if statement should change to `InIntervalCounter >= WorkingInterval` and `InIntervalCounter >= TotalInterval`, `InIntervalCounter > WorkingInterval` may cause the 1 second delay.